# How to enable mic in webchat.js give by Microsoft bot framework. for PVA bot

Tags: javascript, botframework, chatbot, web-chat, power-virtual-agents

We have developed bot in PVA. We are using webchat,js for the UI of our BOT. I need send button to change from [Without Mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa8s6.png) to [Mic Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqciv.png) .

We can achieve this using botchat.js but we have some styling issues with botchat.js so we thought of using webchat.js but in this we are unable to use mic input.

Need help for enabling mic input using webchat.js.

Thanks,

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2855#issuecomment-582838400) might help in resolving the microphone issue with webchat.js.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue is different to what I am facing.